# Why Re-Arranging Code Outputs Differently?

Tags: php, urlencode

Good Day,

Below I have provided 2 codes, which I did not write but grabbed from a forum. I really need to learn the solution to this new mystery. Both make use of the urlencode(). They are nearly the same code.
I notice that, only the 1st code's output is normal and not encoded while the 2nd one's output is encoded. Why ?
Since both are making use of the urlencode() then shouldn't both their outputs be in encoded format ? This has been greatly puzzling me for days now. I give-up. What's the mystery behind this ?

1st Code:

```
$url = 'http://nogdog.com/cat/subcat?var 1=value 1&var2=2&this other=thing&number is=12';
echo prepare_url($url) . "\n";

function prepare_url($url) {
  $url_parts = parse_url($url);
  if($url_parts === false or empty($url_parts['host'])) {
    return false;
  }
  $url_out = preg_match('/^https?/i', $url_parts['scheme']) ? strtolower($url_parts['scheme']) : 'https';
  $url_out .= "://{$url_parts['host']}{$url_parts['path']}";
  if(!empty($url_parts['query'])) {
    parse_str($url_parts['query'], $query_parts);
    foreach($query_parts as $q_key => $q_value) {
      $query_string_parts[] = urlencode($q_key).'='.urlencode($q_value);
    }
    $url_out .= '?'.implode('&', $query_string_parts);
  }
  return $url_out;
}
```

2nd Code:

```
function prepare_url2($url) {
  $url_parts = parse_url($url);
  if($url_parts === false or empty($url_parts['host'])) {
    return false;
  }
  // re-assemble the start of url string
  $url_start = preg_match('/^https?/i', $url_parts['scheme']) ? strtolower($url_parts['scheme']) : 'https';
  $url_start .= "://{$url_parts['host']}{$url_parts['path']}"; 
  // rawurlencode the start of url string
  $url_out = rawurlencode($url_start);
  if(!empty($url_parts['query'])) {
    parse_str($url_parts['query'], $query_parts);
    foreach($query_parts as $q_key => $q_value) {
        // assemble and check if value is numeric
      $query_string_parts[] = urlencode($q_key).'='.(is_numeric($q_value) ? intval($q_value) :urlencode($q_value));
    }
    $url_out .= '?'.implode('&', $query_string_parts);
  }
 
  return $url_out;
}

$url = 'http://zorg.com/cat/subcat?var 1=value 1&var2=2&this other=thing&number is=13';
echo prepare_url2($url);
```

**NOTE
The difference between the two codes are that, the 1st one defines the $url and calls the prepare_url() function at the top. (Before the prepare_url() function's code).**

```
$url = 'http://nogdog.com/cat/subcat?var 1=value 1&var2=2&this other=thing&number is=12';
echo prepare_url($url) . "\n";
```

While, the 2nd one defines the $url and calls the prepare_url() function at the bottom. (After the prepare_url() function's code).

```
$url = 'http://zorg.com/cat/subcat?var 1=value 1&var2=2&this other=thing&number is=13';
echo prepare_url($url);
```

Apart from that, both codes are the same.
So, if both the codes are the same (so to speak), then why does the 1st code output like this:

```
http://nogdog.com/cat/subcat?var_1=value+1&var2=2&this_other=thing&number_is=12
```

And, why does the 2nd code output like this:

```
http%3A%2F%2Fzorg.com%2Fcat%2Fsubcat?var_1=value+1&var2=2&this_other=thing&number_is=13
```

Comment: `rawurlencode($url_start);`

Comment: @berend, Thanks! Are you saying I should remove this line ? $url_out = rawurlencode($url_start);
Do answer after checking the 2nd code again. - Cheers!

Comment: @berend, Do you mind updating my 2nd code to fix it so I can go and accept your answer and close this thread ? - Thank you very much for your time & effort!

Comment: @berend, You pointed-out the raw_urlencode() is causing the issue. But where should I place the raw_urlencode() to fix the issue ?

Comment: @dharman, Can you help me on this thread ?

Comment: @tushar, Can you start from where berend left-off answering my question ?

Comment: @lessmore, Can you show me where I should've added the raw_urlencode() in my code ?